# Custom block created with GUI stripping some <a> tags, not all of them

Tags: 8, blocks

I am creating a custom block in D8; the block includes the following HTML:

```
<div class="header__action-items">
  <a class="btn btn-large" href="help">Donate Now</a>
  <a class="btn btn-large" href="me">Connect With Us</a>
  <a class="nav-toggle nav-toggle-menu icon-menu" href="#nav">Menu</a>
</div>
```

I have saved the block using the Full HTML format and placed it into the header region, here is a screenshot of what is added to the page:

[image: screenshot of injected HTML]

I have disabled JS and re-loaded the page to make sure nothing else was happening.  Here is a screenshot of the edit screen:

[image: screenshot of wysiwyg]

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar question recently and the problem was CKEditor, could be the same here.

If you want to be sure that your markup is not altered in any way, create a text format without ckeditor and use that.